# Find the equation of the line that is parallel to the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Find the equation of the line that is parallel to the plane
$σ:x-3y+2z-7=0$

It is also perpendicular to the line:
$p:X=[-4,0,1]+t(3,-3,1)$
and passes through the point $[-5,2,1]$

I'm not entirely sure if such line equation exists at all. I found an equation that is parallel to the plane, and that passes through the point $[-5,2,1]$, but I'm not sure about the perpendicularity. And if that's not possible, I'm not sure how to justify it properly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plane $\sigma$ can be rewritten in the form $\mathbf r \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = 7$, which is in the standard form $\mathbf r\cdot \mathbf n = k$ for a plane, where $\mathbf n$ is the normal vector to $\sigma$.
The required line is parallel to the plane, and is thus perpendicular to $\mathbf n$.

The required line must also be perpendicular to $p$, which has direction vector $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Thus the direction of our wanted line is parallel to $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 6\end{pmatrix}.$$

We know the line passes through $(-5, 2, 1)$, so the final equation of the line is $$L: \begin{pmatrix} -5 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}, \;\lambda\in \mathbb R.$$

Answer (score 1):

The first condition requires that the line is perpendicular to the vector $v_1=(1,-3,2)$ the second condition requires that the line is also perpendicular to the vector $v_2=(3,-3,1)$ then a direction vector for the line can be found by cross product $v=v_1\times v_2$ then finally the line is given by $[-5,2,1]+t\cdot v$.

Comment: Was writing the same thing. [$(1,-3,2)\times(3,-3,1) = (3,5,6)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2C-3%2C2%29+cross+%283%2C-3%2C1%29)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin That's a pretty standard method indeed! I didn't fill all the steps in orther to let some work for the OP.